# Git- link on local master branch works, doesn't work on live version

Tags: django, git, github, version-control

I am working on a Python/ Django project, using Git to manage the version control.

I'm currently having an issue with some inconsistency between the `master` branch on my local machine and the live `master` branch on the server...

I fixed a bug on my local machine earlier, and pushed the changes to the server, however, a link on one of the pages on the live version on the server is now no longer working, even though it is on my local version...

The link is at: www.mysite.co.uk/costing/id/ - when I click on the link 'Reports', I get an error page that says:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /costing/6108/payment-report/overview/
>
> Invalid block tag on line 87: 'date_to_display', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

But on my local machine, on the `master` branch, this link works correctly.

Having looked at the template where the live version is complaining about the the `invalid block tag`, I can see that it is in the block:

```
{% block content_payment_schedule %}
    {% if not webview %}
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="project-name">{{project.project_name|upper}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Display today's date in the header -->
                    <td> {{ date_to_display }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>  
    {% endif %}
    ...
{% endblock content_payment_schedule %}
```

This was something that I had previously added to the code (to display the date in the header of a PDF generated by clicking a link), and has been working up until now...

When I browse to: localhost:8000/costing/id/ and click on the same 'Reports' link, I am taken to the reports page at: localhost:8000/costing/id/payment-report/overview/ (which displays a 'tabbed content' area, with tabs for various reports, with the 'overview' tab automatically selected).

From local machine, while on `master` branch, if I try running

`git commit -m 'message about commit'`, & then

`git push origin master`

Git displays a message telling me that:

> Everything up-to-date

`git status` displays a message saying:

> On branch master
>
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

So why is it that I am getting this `TemplateSyntaxError` on the live version, when my local version works correctly, and the version on the server is up-to-date with my local version?

Comment: Did you check, whether you use the same settings files. Do the differ? Are you sure, that the file containing your tag `date_to_display` is on the server?

Comment: If the live version of the code uses `{{ date_to_display }}` then it looks as if you have already pulled the latest version of the code. In that case, I think the problem is that you haven't restarted the server.

Comment: I have restarted the server several times- this variable was added several weeks ago, and I have fixed a number of bugs since then- restarting the server every time I have pushed my changes to it...

Comment: You only [fixed the bug on Friday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505414/django-templatesyntaxerror-error-during-template-rendering). Either the live server still has `{% date_to_display %}`, in which case you have to pull the latest version of the code, or the live server has `{{ date_to_display }}`, in which case you have to restart the server. The code you have shown, `{{ date_to_display }}` would not cause the error `Invalid block tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Now for your local repo, git status says:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then you can fetch from remote repo by `git fetch origin`, and use `git status` to show the local master branch. If it says,

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

that means, your local master branch is not the newest version. If you want the live version (remote master branch) stay same with local master branch, you can use `git push -f origin master`.